# Statistical analysis pre + post testing- with control and intervention 35 participants

Tags: dataset

What statistical analysis would I use when testing 35 participants. pre & post test and checking for changes after 1 intervention and a control group with no intervention?
I have one mediating variable, 3 independent variables and two dependent variables.

Answer (score 1):

Is your dataset normally distributed or not?

Supposing it is, you could perform paired T-tests, testing for significantly different responses in the pre and post.

Supposing it is not normally distributed, you could perform the non-parametric McNemar's (Bowker's) test to receive basically the same information as a T-test.

Your sample size is on the lower end so I would not recommend performing regression.